# Spring Error during execution of processor

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Full error is:

> Error during execution of processor
>   'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'
>   (search:12)

My search.html page displays when I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!--<meta charset="UTF-8">-->
    <title>Search Users</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Search Users</h3>
<form th:action="@{/user/search}" th:object="${searchCriteria}" method="post">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" value="*{firstname}"/></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" value="${searchCritera.lastname}"/></p>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I then changed `value` to `th:field` for `*{firstname}` and `${searchCritera.lastname}` as below:

```
<form th:action="@{/user/search}" th:object="${searchCriteria}" method="post">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}"/></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" th:field="${searchCritera.lastname}"/></p>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Now I get the error above and can't seem to fix it. I tried `th:value` but it throws another error:

> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "searchCritera.lastname"
>   (search:12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you're using dollar signs, use `th:`:

```
<input type="text" th:value="${searchCriteria.lastname}"/>
```

And spell the variable name correctly.

Also include `name=` or `th:field=` as appropriate (or instead, depending on what you're trying to accomplish).